# Why is the probability dP of finding an object (e.g. galaxy) in an infinitesmal volume dV equal to \overline{n}dV?

Tags: galaxy, cosmology, dark-matter

As pointed out by many cosmology lectures, such as **Eq. (63)** of [Cosmology II-8 Structure Formation](https://www.mv.helsinki.fi/home/hkurkisu/Cosm8.pdf), and **Eq. (3.1)** of [A Detailed Look at Estimators for the Two-Point Correlation Function](https://www2.physik.uni-bielefeld.de/fileadmin/user_upload/theory_e6/Master_Theses/MA_MarianBiermann.pdf), the probability of finding an
object in an infinitesimal volume is
$$
dP=\overline{n}dV,
$$
where $\overline{n}$ is the mean number density. In my opinion, $\overline{n}dV$ is just the number of objects in $dV$ and can be greater than one. However, the probability should be less or equal to one. **I don't understand why $\overline{n}dV$ is the probability of finding an object in the volume**.

Comment: Note cross posting is very strongly discouraged and you have posted this on [Physics SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/49794/why-is-the-probability-dp-of-finding-an-object-e-g-galaxy-in-an-infinitesmal) as well.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine I have deleted the post on Physics SE.

Comment: n-bar can be grater than 1, but dV is an infinitesimal, so n-bar x dV doesn't really even have a "value", you really need to integrate it over a volume to have it make sense.

Comment: In addition to what @GrapefruitIsAwesome says, note that (between eqs. 61 and 62) it is assumed that $dV$ is "_so small that there is at most one galaxy in it_."

Comment: @pela Does "so small that there is at most one galaxy in it" means that the maximum of $dP$ is one?

Comment: I think it's more correct to say that it's so small that $dP\ll1$.

Comment: @pela Ok, I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That the probability of galaxy occupation is $\bar{n}\ dV$ will work as an approximation so long as you are considering volumes that are limited in size such that the probability is $\ll 1$. i.e. You are ignoring any probability that there could be more than 1 galaxy in the volume.

If you have $N$ particles in box of volume $V$, then $\bar{n} = N/V$.
The probability of finding a particular particle in a subset of the volume $dV$ will be $dV/V$. But if there are $N$ particles then the probability that *any* of them are in $dV$ will be $N\ dV/V = \bar{n}\ dV$.

But this probability will include cases where there are 1, 2, 3 or more particles in the box.

The probability of getting 2 particles in $dV$ will be $N\ (dV/V) \times (N-1)\ (dV/V)$. But if $N\ (dV/V) \ll 1$, then the probability of finding a second particle (or more) in the box is $\lll 1$ and could be ignored.

The approximation will break down as the probability rises, even to a small fraction, because there is a tendency to find galaxies in groups and clusters (thanks to gravity).

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. BTW, what do you think of my answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

**Here are my thoughts on this issue and comments are welcome.**

If there are $M$ ensembles of volume elements, i.e. $dV$, and there are $N$ volume elements containing particles, then the probability of finding an object in an infinitesimal volume is
$$
dP = N/M.
$$

Also, assuming that $n_i$ is the particle (or galaxy) number density of the $i$-th volume element, then we get
$$
\begin{align}
dP &= (\Sigma_{i=1}^{M}(n_i\cdot dV))/M \\
&= (\Sigma_{i=1}^{M}n_i/M)\cdot dV \\
&= \overline{n}dV
\end{align},
$$
where $\overline{n}=(\Sigma_{i=1}^{M}n_i/M)$ is the mean number density.